# What's the verb to describe the onset of a disease?

Tags: word-request

I know that "onset" is a noun. I'm trying to find a verb to convey the onset of a disease. For instance, I need to make a list of things that are not covered by a medical insurance product, and one of the items is something like this:

> - Congenital disease that ***<verb>*** or is confirmed by the insured before the age of 8

What verb would I put there to mean "onset"? Or how could I reword the phrase while keeping "congenital disease" as the focus of the phrase?

I've seen somebody write "Congenital disease that ***is infested*** or confirmed by the insured before the age of 8" and I find it a little weird. I can't find any supporting reference that says the verb "to infest" can be used this way.

I have had other people suggest "to contract", but that's definitely wrong because contraction is not the same as onset, and would not make sense for congenital diseases anyway.

Comment: I think they may have meant _manifested_ not _infested_.

Comment: **Manifests itself** (agree with mdewey) or **is diagnosed** would fit.

Comment: The choice between **manifest** and **diagnose** may depend on the purpose of the document being drafted. A congenital condition might be diagnosed before it has manifested.

Comment: infested is for bugs in your house. :)

Answer (score 1):

Taking your original

> Congenital disease that *verb* or is confirmed by the insured before the age of 8

You could say

> Congenital disease that was first manifested or is confirmed by the insured before the age of 8

This unfortunately reads as though the insured had to confirm it before he or she reached the age of 8 which is clearly absurd

> Congenital disease that was diagnosed or is confirmed by the insured before the age of 8

This is possible but as @WeatherVane pointed out a disease can be manifest before it is diagnosed and diagnosed before it is manifested. For instance a chromosomal abnormality could be identified well before any clinical signs or symptoms.

It might be better to split this into two questions depending on exactly what you are trying to determine but I think we are then straying into an area where either the medical or legal site might provide more authoritative answers.

Comment: *"either the medical or legal site might provide more authoritative answers"* Absolutely. You need the correct terms. It is even possible that the legal language is different from the medical language. I suggest you ask on [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) first and then check the answer on [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/)